# Как получить пути ко всем домашним каталогам всех пользователей?

Tags: shell, bash, linux

Мне необходимо получить пути всех домашних каталогов пользователей.

В принципе можно отталкиваться от того, что они лежат в /home/, но путь пользователя root находится в /root. Возможно есть какой-нибуть универсальный способ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В /etc/passwd же всё написано, не устраивает такой вариант?